# Implement a marker trait for tuple `(L, R)` if either `L` or `R` implements it

Tags: rust, traits, implements

I have a marker trait `PoisonPill` which is implemented by certain structs. I would like to implement it for a tuple `(L, R)` if EITHER `L` or `R` implements `PoisonPill` (not necessarily both). Is it possible to do that in Rust 2018, and how? Preferably stable Rust.

I tried the following:

```rust
trait PoisonPill {}

impl<L, R: PoisonPill> PoisonPill for (L, R) {}
impl<L: PoisonPill, R> PoisonPill for (L, R) {}
```

but get the `E0119` compiler error because of overlapping definitions.

Comment: There is currently [no way](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42721) to tell the compiler that `L` and `R` respectively do not implement `PoisonPill`, which would solve your problem. [Specialization](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/language-features/specialization.html) may also help, but it is currently unstable.

Comment: Partial specialization is currently not correctly designed and implemented in Rust 2018, and even unreasonably not scheduled.